# Boolean modifier does not work correctly

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to apply a boolean modifier on a plane that is located exactly at the place where to objects connect to each other (their borderline vertices belong to the plane of the "Plane" object). I the plane to be cut according to the shape of those corridor object. Let's say take the shape of the doorway inside. However, when I apply a boolean modifier either nothing happens or the plane disappears completely.

[image]

Comment: This is supposed to work... but it's hard to see the objects geometry from the picture (inner parts, normals, etc.). Could you add more details or upload a file with the needed mesh?

Comment: Booleans only work on manifold meshes with actual volume. A plane is flat  with no "internal space" so no Boolean operations may be executed on it